# Android RecyclerView: What is the type of the date in between chat items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As you all may know usually in chat applications like (whatsapp, messenger....) you will notice that chat items include a date item in between. Now I researched this and I noticed that it has to do with what is called by **multiple view types.**

**But**

If it is really a multiple viewtype thing, then how come it works like that. Example lets say I have a chat app with blue item, green item, and a date then I should do this:

```
    public int getItemViewType(int position){

     ItemMessage item = my_list.get(position);

     if(item.getType.equals("blue")){

       return BLUE;

     }else if(item.getType.equals("green")){

       return GREEN;
     }else{
       return 0;
     }  
}
```

Until here I know what item to show blue (going message) and green (the coming one).

**My question**: what about the date item, Is it an item that is added to the database? Or is it a view in the item that gets hidden or shown? How do these chat apps do it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I know that the date comes from the server, but I am taking about the date object in between the chat objects. I store my data as json on the server it looks like this:

```
      chat_messages
       |
       |
       ---item1
          |
          |----message: "hello"
          |----type: "green"
          |----timestamp:...... 

      ----item2
          |
          |---message: "hey there"
          |---type: "blue"
          |---timestamp:.........
```

above if I retrieve I will get this in the recyclerview

```
          |-------------
            item 1
          |-------------

                        |----------------
                          item 2
                        |----------------
```

my question again is should the date be considered an item also like this:

```
         date_item
         |
         |---type: "date"
         |---timestamp: .....
```

hopefully I explained it well.

Comment: It's unclear what your'e asking. If I got you right, the date is just a TextView that get 'binded' in the OnBind function no matter GREEN BLUE or YELLOW.

Comment: @FlyingNades I know that it is a text view. But my question is that if I am retrieving chat from a server then should the date be a data in the database or its just a view in the blue or the green items that gets hidden or shown?

Comment: I dont fully get your question, but the date of the message comes from the database, I really dont get the other option. Ill make an answer with the Progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET request -> you now have the data (either `GREEN` or `BLUE` type).
data contains the type, as you said, and the date.

The date is the same, either you get a `BLUE` type or a `GREEN` type.

So **yes**.. the date comes from the server.

**EDIT:** No, it should not, your item architecture should be as follows:

```
item1
-----------
   message: "hey"
   type: "green"
   date: "13.1.2004"
   timestamp: "..."
   ...
```

Comment: can you please check the edit.

Comment: @database check my edit.

Comment: okay thanks for your help.